# php --enable-calendar=shared

Tags: compiling, php, calendar

I have on my Arch linux system, php compiled with `--enable-calendar=shared`, what does that mean? 
I couldn't find any relevant information on that topic on the web.

Problem is, that I have to recompile it with --enable-calendar flag, for some application to work, should I remove `=shared`, as it is not working right now, complaining that I don't have that extension installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP extensions can be compiled statically or shared.

- Static compilation puts the extension directly into PHP (therefore it does not need to be loaded and cannot be unloaded).
- When using shared compilation `--enable-calendar=shared` that will create file `calendar.so`. You can enable or disable it by editing `php.ini`.